# Select rows from dataframe by checking the value of other column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
|role_num|   email_address|role|counters  |
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
|     110| EMAIL2@TEST.COM|null|         2|
|     110| EMAIL2@TEST.COM| P  |         2|
|     114|EMAIL10@TEST.COM| A  |         2|
|     114|EMAIL10@TEST.COM|null|         2|
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
```

From this dataframe, my output should be like below:

```
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
|role_num|   email_address|role|counters  |
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
|     110| EMAIL2@TEST.COM| P  |         2|
|     114|EMAIL10@TEST.COM| A  |         2|
+--------+----------------+----+----------+
```

The condition is whenever the duplicates count is 2 then I should select the role "P" but if that role is not there then I need to select "A".

I have tried like below. But this doesn't seem working.

```
import sc.implicits._

val targetDF = Seq(
      ("110", "EMAIL2@TEST.COM", "", "2"),
      ("110", "EMAIL2@TEST.COM", "PAH", "2"),
      ("114", "EMAIL10@TEST.COM", "AAH", "2"),
      ("114", "EMAIL10@TEST.COM", "", "2")
      )
      .toDF(
        "role_num",
        "email_address",
        "role",
        "counters")

targetDF.where(
        (col("counters") > 1 )
           || ?)
```

Can you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work with your current roles:

```
targetDF
      .withColumn("priority", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("acct_num").orderBy(desc_nulls_last("role"))))
      .where(col("priority") === 1)
      .drop("priority")
```